# Tu en tires, une gueule

Tags: sens

I have heard the following sentence in the TV series "Marseille":

- Tu en tires, une gueule.

Context: A mobster and a polician running for mayor are walking and talking with each other about the campaign. The mobster steps aside for some seconds to talk on the phone. Meanwhile, the politician reads in his news feed in his cellphone that the press found invoices which supposedly were faked by the politician's party some years ago. He immediately becomes worried and his face shows it. That's when the mobster says the sentence above.

What does "tu en tires" mean here? I have not found a suitable meaning in Word Reference and Larousse dicts, but possibly I may have missed it, as "tirer" has so many meanings. I know the subject is the politician's long face, but I don't understand what exactly is meant.

Comment: Correct spelling is "gueule" ;) https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gueule

Comment: @JKHA Fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This, clearly refers to [this page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tirer_la_tronche), with "gueule" instead of "tronche", which is even less formal langage.

> [tirer la tronche](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tirer_la_tronche) : (informal) to sulk, to pout, to be in a huff

In this case, we use the form : "tu en tires, une gueule" to reproach someone else to be sulking, to be poutting or to be in a huff. It looks like a French way of: "What's the long face for?" or "Why so glum?".

In this particular scene in TV Show Marseille, the mobster says that, because there is quite a bad news read by the politician, and this is clearly seeable on his face (gueule).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And why the pronoun "en" ?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista I've edited, tell me if this answers.